# What is this exercise from A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory trying to say?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here is the 21st exercise from the second chapter of A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory.

> Define $\bigwedge(n) = \log{p}$ if $n$ is a power of $p$ and zero otherwise. Prove that $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) \log{d} = \bigwedge(n)$. [*Hint*: First calculate $\sum_{d \mid n} \bigwedge(d)$ and then apply the Möbius inversion formula.]

I don't understand the definition of this function. For instance, one possible meaning is

> Define $\bigwedge(n) = \log{p}$ if there exists some $p$ such that $n$ is a power of $p$ and zero otherwise.

However, this $p$ is almost never unique so the definition is nonsensical. Another possible meaning is

> Fix $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $\bigwedge(n) = \log{p}$ if $n$ is a power of $p$ and zero otherwise.

But then in the equation

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) \log{d} = \bigwedge(n)$$

the left-hand side is independent of $p$ and the right-hand side isn't. It isn't hard to find counterexamples to it, too.

What is the exercise trying to tell me?

Comment: If $n=p^k$, then $\Lambda(n)=log(p)$. Otherwise, it's zero.

Comment: I understand this. But I'm unsure of whether the $p$ is fixed a priori, whether it's not or whether there is some third interpretation of this. For instance, is $\bigwedge(2^5) = \log{2}$, while $\bigwedge(5^2) = \log{5}$ or is one of them zero?

Comment: @zaq I suspect that $p$ is supposed to range over *primes*: if $n$ is a prime power, then it is a power of exactly one prime. So e.g. $\bigwedge(32)=\log 2$, $\bigwedge(25)=\log 5$, and $\bigwedge(36)=0$ since $6$ isn't a prime.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, this makes sense. I had thought of this, but it slipped past me after I got confused over the $p$ being fixed or not. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: The definition is $\Lambda(n)=\log p$ if $p$ is a prime and $n=p^k$ for some $k>0.$ So $$\Lambda(1)=0,\Lambda(2)=\log 2,\Lambda(3)=\log 3,\Lambda(4)=\log 2, ..., \Lambda (6)=0,...$$

Comment: This function's usual name is `\Lambda`, not `\bigwedge`